# Acting based on IE version number in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Can someone please help me understand why I am getting the wrong output...

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
set VALUE_NAME="Version"
For /F "tokens=3*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME%') Do (
 set versionNumber=%%A
)
echo %versionNumber%
if %versionNumber% GEQ 10 echo %versionNumber%
pause
```

Output:
    9.10.9200.1686
    9.10.9200.1686
    Please press any key to continue. . .

The ouput should just be printing the versionNumber once. Can you not treat a registry key value like an integer and do the above if GEQ 10 comparison?

Let me know...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set "KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
set "VALUE_NAME=Version"
For /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%"') Do (
 set "versionNumber=%%B"
)
for /f "delims=." %%a in ("%versionNumber%") do set "versionNumber=%%a"
echo %versionNumber%
if %versionNumber% GEQ 10 echo %versionNumber%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works indeed :) ... could you clarify a bit why the above does NOT work though?

Comment: @user2008222    `cmd` can _not_ handle decimal numbers, eg. **3.1415692**. You can compare only strings and integers to `+/- 2^31-1` (2147483647).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393 the above answer will only work correctly up to IE9

Combining that answer with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549699/internet-explorer-11-detection-from-batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set versionNumber=3
set regquery=reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%regquery%') do (
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do (
    if %%b GEQ 10 (
       set versionNumber=%%b
    )
  )
)
if %versionNumber% LSS 10 (
  set regquery=reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version 
  for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%regquery%') do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set versionNumber=%%b
    )
  )    
)
ECHO IE Version %versionNumber%
if %versionNumber% GEQ 10 ECHO Internet explorer 10 or higher
```

I set versionNumber to 3 at the start as before IE4 there isn't a Version set in the registry not that anyone is likely to be find IE3 or early these days