# Internet Explorer 11 detection from Batch File

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I would like to ask you if there is a way  in a batch file to do the following:

1) Read Internet explorer version from the registry.

2) If internet explorer is less than version 11 pop up a message "you are running a different version of Internet explorer. Application will close" and then exit application after pressing a button;

3) If internet explorer is 11 or higher  then pop up message "You are running Internet explorer 11 or higher";

A Reg file will then be imported from c:\myfolder and then batch file should show up something like "Operation finished.Press one button to close window".

I know IE 11 places a hive called  "svcVersion" in the following path

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer

I wonder if any of you might be help me how to "instruct" the batch file to read  from the registry looking for that parameter and then do as above.
Thank you very much indeed for your help.
Meleena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
set regquery=reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%regquery%') do (
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do (
    if %%b LSS 11 echo you are running a different version of Internet explorer. Application will close & goto :eof
    if %%b GEQ 11 (
       echo You are running Internet explorer 11 or higher.
       echo REGEDIT /S C:\myfolder\myfile.reg
       echo Operation finished. Press any key to close window.
       pause>nul
    )
  )
)
```

Remove the echo before regedit after you change myfile.reg the the correct name.

Comment: Hi Matt and thanks for your help.
I did not know that in systems not running IE11 the 'svcVersion' string into “HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer” does not exist  so the batch should query the registry looking for ‘svcVersion’  into that path  (sorry my bad).
1) If it finds it should show up "you are running internet explorer 11",
   apply myregfile.reg and close after pressing a button,
2) if it does not find just show up "you are not running internet explorer 11"
   and close after pressing a button

Comment: I tried to use
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion
IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO IE11
IF %errorlevel%==1 GOTO NOTIE11
:IE11
echo "This is IE 11"
REGEDIT /S C:\myfolder\myfile.reg
echo "operation completed.Press any key to close window"
pause>nul
exit
:NOTIE11
echo "you are not running IE11.Press any key to close window"
pause>nul
exit.
But when I run Reg Query I get the output visible on the screen 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    svcVersion    REG_SZ    11.0.9600.16476
which I would like to hide.  Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I have IE10 and I have svcVersion in my registry. To not display the output, send it to nul. `reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion >nul`